# How to substract dates in SQL stored procedure?

Tags: sql-server-2008, datetime, stored-procedures

I am writing a stored procedure in SQL Server 2008. Here I have a database table as

```
Id       LastUpdateTime
1        2011-12-27 11:15:03.700
2        2011-12-27 11:16:03.700
3        2011-12-27 11:15:03.700
```

In my stored procedure, I want to check that

```
if (currentSystemTime - LastUpdateTime > 5 minute)
{
   // some action
}
else
{
   // some other action
}
```

But I am not getting how to do that. Please help me. Thanks in advance

Comment: I think if you look at the answers below we all used the same link so it wasn't too hard to do a quick Google search to find the answer to this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at using the [DateDiff](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx) function:

```
DATEDIFF(minute, cuurentSystemTime, LastUpdateTime)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the [DATEDIFF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx) function.

```
if (DATEDIFF(minute, cuurentSystemTim, LastUpdateTime) > 5)
{
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use DATEDIFF ( datepart , startdate , enddate ). See  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794(v=sql.90).aspx